# Children's book about fairies and purple cards with poems

Tags: story-identification, childrens-novel, fairy

I don’t remember much but it was a children's book.

I’m pretty sure it was about fairies, inside there were small inserts that were purple pieces of card with poems on.

Comment: Hi there! :) this is a bit vague, I know you said you didn't remember much, but maybe you could take a look at [this guide on how to ask a good story-ID question](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/98028), see if that triggers any more memories you could [edit] in? For instance, when did you read that? Was it written in English, was it a translation? Any recollection what the cover looked like? Stuff like that, to increase the chances of a successful identification - every single detail can be important. Cheers!

Answer (score 5):

### [*Flower Children: The Little Cousins of the Field and Garden*](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/46934/46934-h/46934-h.htm) by Elizabeth Gordon and illustrated by M. T. Ross

Originally published in 1910 it has been re-published numerous times and so there was likely an edition out there that was mainly purple in colour. The foreward starts off as:

> ALL children are flowers in the garden of God’s love. A flower is the mystical counterpart of a child. To the understanding heart a child is a flower and a flower is a child. God made flowers on the day that He made the world beautiful. Then He gave the world children to play amid the flowers. God has implanted in the breasts of children a natural love for flowers—and no one who keeps that love in his heart has entirely forsaken the land of childhood.

The first poem in the book is as follows:

> [image: First poem image]
>
> SAID CROCUS: “My! this wind is cold!
> Most wish I had not been so bold;
> Here the fields are still all brown;
> Glad I wore my eider-down.”

What I believe is the original cover looks like the below:

[image: Flower Children: The Little Cousins of the Field and Garden front cover]